# JSBridge for Qt5

Tags: qt5, qtwebengine

I found that Swift had a framework called `WebViewJavascriptBridge` which you can register bridge like:

```
bridge = WebViewJavascriptBridge(webview)!
bridge.setWebViewDelegate(delegate)
bridge.registerHandler("readConfigString")
```

I want to rewrite it C++ in Qt5, so I'm wondering if there is such framework in Qt5?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is QtWebChannel